# Invoking a webservice with a get request

Tags: web-services, soap

if i have a wdsl document, i just want to call the webservice with a get request and put the parameters in the URL. Is this possible or do i have to use SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL determines whether or not you can call it using a GET request. Most likely, you cannot.

What programming language are you using? In Java or C#, it's pretty easy to let the tools generate code for you that will do all the hard work of calling the service.